# Как заставить TcpListener обвалиться по таймауту?

Tags: c#, .net, сокет

Добрый день.

Для ожидания входящих подключений я использую класс `TcpListener`.
Что делать, если у меня таймаут на ожидание нового подключения = 30 секунд, а установка `Server.ReceiveTimeout` не срабатывает?

Код:

```
            SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
            SMTP_Listener.Server.ReceiveTimeout = timeout; // не срабатывает
            SMTP_Listener.Start();

 SMTP_Listener.Server.ReceiveTimeout = 5;

            while (true)
            {
                Socket clientSocket = SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket();
                // висим на этой строчке и все, никуда дальше. Как таймаут сделать?

                if (clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                }

                Console.WriteLine("***");
            }
```

Спасибо

Comment: А зачем? это рабочий процесс. Цикл организовуется примерно так.

Comment: на AcceptSocket() висит процесс, а я хочу по истечении времени его прервать, сообщение выдать, например. Как это тут сделать?

Comment: Обычно создают отдельный Thread, который можно остановить. Создать Thread - Сделать Sleep потом Abort.  А вот одна из статей https://habrahabr.ru/post/120157/  для примера, сам по ним делал сокеты.

Comment: ReceiveTimeout - это не тот таймаут, это таймаут на Receive не на Accept.

Comment: @nick_n_a: Abort? Эээ... Функцией Abort пользоваться _нельзя_. Это прямой путь к разрушенной памяти и дедлокам. Не учите ТС плохому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
SMTP_Listener.Server.Poll(timeout, SelectMode.SelectRead);
```

Этот метод должен вернуть `true` если есть входящее соединение (в таком случае можно уже вызывать `AcceptSocket`/`AcceptTcpClient`, они отработают без блокировки). Если вышел тайм-аут - метод вернет `false`.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло